# Can't mount Samba share on Raspbian, works flawless on Debian

Tags: linux, raspbian, mount, samba, cifs

I have a samba share that I use in my home, this works fine on both Windows and Debian, but when trying to mount it on my Raspberry Pi I just get an error.

`/etc/fstab`:

```
//media.lan/public /media/media.lan cifs guest, uid=1000 0 0
```

`dmesg`:

```
[ 1497. 700485] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 1497. 703604] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

```
root@webcam:/home/pi# mount -a
mount error (13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs (8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
root@webcam:/home/pi#
```

Samba config: pastebin.com/dHjDUtMh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It look like you forget security option in your command, try this one:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //server-name/sharename /mnt/mntdir -o credentials=.mycredentials,sec=ntlmssp
```

If this one don't work change security from `ntlmssp` to `ntlmv2`.

EDIT:
Look like `ntlmv2` is used more often

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm, any reason why i didn't had to provide this on my Debian system?

Comment: Nope, maybe because Raspbian is a lightweight version of Debian.

If it's help please validate my answer ;)

Comment: @HwT Which security option did you choose ? Maybe it will help other people.